# How can I write tests for specific dates and time zones in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I am using Jest for writing my tests.

I would like to write tests for specific dates and time zones. I already found some solutions for this, but they are not exactly what I need.

**Dates:**

I know that I can use `jest.setSystemTime()` to write tests for specific dates. The problem is that I am using a custom date object that extends from the built-in date object. For example, if I run:

```
jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-10-05'));

console.log(new Date());
console.log(new CustomDate());
```

`new Date()` shows the date I set, but `new CustomDate()` still shows the current moment. How can I fix that?

**Time zones:**

I know that I can set my time zone when I run jest, for example:

```
TZ="Australia/Sydney" yarn test
```

I can also set the time zone in the *jest.config.js* file.

While both these solutions work, I would have to manually change the time zone and run my tests many times.

Is there a way to change the time zone inside the test itself?

How can I write tests for specific dates and time zones in JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you just mock `CustomDate`?